# What's wrong with the syntax of this create table query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried changing the table name to match and 'matches' but I still get the same error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''match' (r1 VARCHAR(5), r2 VARCHAR(5), r3 VARCHAR(5), r4 VARCHAR(5), r5 VARCH...' at line 1
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE 'match' (r1 VARCHAR(5), r2 VARCHAR(5), r3 VARCHAR(5), r4 VARCHAR(5), r5 VARCHAR(5));
```

Comment: In mysql you should use back ticks instead of single quotes for the table name.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra ... better yet, don't name your tables using MariaDB keywords like `MATCH`. ..

Comment: `MATCH` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match is a reserved word, use matches again without the single quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE matches (r1 VARCHAR(5), r2 VARCHAR(5), r3 VARCHAR(5), r4 VARCHAR(5), r5 VARCHAR(5));
```

hope this helps.